# Integrate Simple Injector with optional ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, simple-injector

I followed this guide https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore for getting a basic app up and running. And it works great.

My needs now are a bit different, however. The Web API in my app is basically an optional endpoint that may not be started. I want to use the Simple Injector for DI across the entire application, however.

In my Program.cs I have the following lines:

```
// REST API
if (Config.ReadSettingBool("StartRestEndpoint", false))
{
    LogManager.Info("Starting REST Endpoint...");
    try
    {
        _httpHost = new HttpHost(
            Config.ReadSetting("HttpHost", "localhost"),
            Config.ReadSetting("HttpPort", 8081),
            Config.ReadSetting("RestEnvironment", "Development"));
        _httpHost.Start();
        LogManager.Info("REST Endpoint started");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogManager.Error($"Failed to start REST endpoint: {e}");
    }
}
```

Now, inside the HttpHost this happens:

```
_webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseUrls()
    .UseUrls(_url)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseEnvironment(_environment)
    .Build();
_webHost.Start();
```

and inside the StartUp is the same code that I linked.

My problem is that the SimpleInjector container is kept (and setup) inside the StartUp and I have no way of getting at it. What I really want is to setup all the non-aspnet core related dependency tree *prior* to executing the StartUp routine and integrating with aspnet core.

That is, the "add application services" part in the below excerpt:

```
private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    // Add application presentation components:
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
    container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

    // Add application services. For instance:
    container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // Allow Simple Injector to resolve services from ASP.NET Core.
    container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app);
}
```

The reason for wanting this is that this app is not a pure Web Api centered around Http. It is a legacy application containing a lot of background threads doing separate work, not all of which should somehow be exposed within an web api. In some environments, the web api should not even be started. You might argue that the application should somehow be split up but given the constraints I have that is simply not an option.

In short: it solves my goal of wanting to use the same DI container, relying on the same services, persistence access and more, across the entire application, with my REST resources being able to utilize parts of the legacy application functionality.

Is this possible, and how can I accomplish that? Or am I using these tools "the wrong way"?

Comment: "What I really want is to setup all the non-aspnet core related dependency tree prior to executing the StartUp". What problem does that solve? Why do you want that?

Comment: Tried to answer this in a more elaborate way in my edit.

Comment: So, why not have 2 separate container instances? Must the application run, per se, with one single `Container` instance? Would it be okay if the Web API got its own container, isolated from the code that runs on background threads?

Comment: It should work, I think... The only downside would be code duplication for the parts that are shared, but I can live with that. Can you comment on how I should think about Singletons ? Would the idea be that they be though of as singletons per container? That's the only tricky issue I can think of. To be honest I didn't consider a separate container setup. If I do that, is there anything else I would have to consider? If you want to write an answer along those lines I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: "code duplication for the parts that are shared". Why would that be? Why can't you use the same `Bootstrap(Container container)` method that is called from both inside `Startup` as from the location where the background application is configured?

Comment: A component registered as `Singleton` will only have one instance _per container instance_. This shouldn't be a problem in most cases, especially as you already stated that "the application should somehow be split up", which will inherently mean multiple app domains and thus multiple instances. For those few registrations where this actually _is_ a problem, create them yourself, once, and feed them to the container using `RegisterInstance`.

Comment: "Why can't you use the same Bootstrap(Container container)". Like a static method that is just responsible for declaring the dependency tree, and called from both places? Sounds like it should work. Sorry for some of these questions, I admit to being new at using these tools. I will try this suggestion and see if works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested. I did the solution suggested by Steven. Thank you very much.

Basically the application becomes:

```
            LogManager.Info("Starting REST Endpoint...");
            try
            {
                _httpHost = new HttpHost(
                    Config.ReadSetting("HttpHost", "localhost"),
                    Config.ReadSetting("HttpPort", 8081),
                    Config.ReadSetting("RestEnvironment", "Development"));
                _httpHost.Start();
                LogManager.Info("REST Endpoint started");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogManager.Error($"Failed to start REST endpoint: {e}");
            }


            LogManager.Info("Starting Monitors...");
            // Set up dependency tree.
            Container _container = new Container();
            BootstrapDependencyInjectionTree.Bootstrap(_container);
            _container.Verify();

            _monitors = new Monitors(_container.GetInstance<IMonitorDefinitionRepository>());
            _monitors.RegisterMonitors();
            _monitors.StartContinuousMonitors();
```

with another container instance being created inside the aspnetcore StartUp type and set up as:

```
    private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Add application presentation components:
        _container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
        _container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

        // Add application services.
        // This creates an object dependency graph that is used to populate all constructor arguments using DI.
        BootstrapDependencyInjectionTree.Bootstrap(_container);

        // Web api only dependencies.
        _container.RegisterSingleton<IMonitorMetaDataProvider, MonitorMetaDataProvider>();

        // Allow Simple Injector to resolve services from ASP.NET Core.
        _container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app);
    }
```

This works as I would expect it.